# Google Spreadsheet Script - Search Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to make the concern appear when I search the Reference Number for the concern. Expected Output: [image: Expected Output]

Whenever I execute the function, instead of the concern appearing, I get an empty box. I do not know what is wrong with my code, because I am really new to Google Apps coding.

My Code:

```js
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;

function SearchOutput() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputForm = ss.getSheetByName("FORM");

  var searchInput = inputForm.getRange("C3").getValue();
  var text = ss.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE").getDataRange().getValue;
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var row = text[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == searchInput) {
      inputForm.getRange("C7").setValues(row[0]);
      inputForm.getRange("C9").setValues(row[1]);
      inputForm.getRange("C11").setValues(row[2]);
      inputForm.getRange("F7").setValues(row[3]);
      inputForm.getRange("F9").setValues(row[4]);
      inputForm.getRange("F11").setValues(row[5]);
      inputForm.getRange("I7").setValues(row[7]);
      inputForm.getRange("I9").setValues(row[6])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The use of getValue in `var text = ss.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE").getDataRange().getValue;` is incorrect as stated in the answer provided by @idfurw. If the answer doesn't fix your issue. Please provide a sample sheet and the error message encountered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest you to `return` when it matches.

```js
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;

function SearchOutput() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inputForm = ss.getSheetByName("FORM");

  var searchInput = inputForm.getRange("C3").getValue();
  var text = ss.getSheetByName("ARCHIVE").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var row = text[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == searchInput) {
      inputForm.getRange("C7").setValue(row[0]);
      inputForm.getRange("C9").setValue(row[1]);
      inputForm.getRange("C11").setValue(row[2]);
      inputForm.getRange("F7").setValue(row[3]);
      inputForm.getRange("F9").setValue(row[4]);
      inputForm.getRange("F11").setValue(row[5]);
      inputForm.getRange("I7").setValue(row[7]);
      inputForm.getRange("I9").setValue(row[6])
      // return;
    }
  }
}
```